# Is http/express required when deploying socket.io web app

Tags: node.js, express, http, socket.io, web-development-server

I'm trying to create a real time chat web app using Socket.io.
I used this code for server running on port 3000.

```
const io = require("socket.io")(3000, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    },
});
```

Now I'm thinking of deploying my web app to railway.

I tried deploying the app to railway, it build successfully. Then updated client side with new server link, but it's not working.
I wanted to ask, will I need a web server (http or express) to handle incomming connections.
If yes, then why was it running fine before on my local machine and now it requires a web server.

Comment: What is "not working". Are there errors on the server? In the browser?  socket.io already creates a node http server instance with this initialisation.

Comment: Did you update the origin when you deployed it to railway? In the sample above it looks like your cors origin is just your local PC. If you haven't updated that in production you'll still have trouble. You should post more info one what specifically isn't working.